# Add a scrollbar to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, swingworker

I'm having some problem finding a way to add a scrollbar in a `JFrame`. I found a method to redirect `System.{in,out,err}` to a `JTextArea` but I was not successful in adding a scrollbar. I hope this question is not redundant.

```
public class console extends JTextArea {    

 public static JTextArea console(final InputStream out, final PrintWriter in) {
    final JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
        @Override protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(out);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) publish(s.nextLine() + "\n");
            return null;
        }
        @Override protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String line : chunks) area.append(line);
        }
    }.execute();
    area.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        private StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (c == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                in.println(line);
                line.setLength(0); 
            } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) { 
                line.setLength(line.length() - 1); 
            } else if (!Character.isISOControl(c)) {
                line.append(e.getKeyChar());
            }
        }
    });

    return area;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PipedInputStream inPipe = new PipedInputStream();
    PipedInputStream outPipe = new PipedInputStream();
    System.setIn(inPipe);
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new PipedOutputStream(outPipe), true));

    PrintWriter inWriter = new PrintWriter(new PipedOutputStream(inPipe), true);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("\"Console\"");

    frame.getContentPane().add(console(outPipe, inWriter));
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

   // my code
  }
```

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener` (generally, but especially with) text components. Instead us a combination of `DocumentListener` and key bindings. Have a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new `JScrollPane` object and set the `ScrollBarPolicies`.

If you do not want to the scollbars to appear always, just delete the policies.

**EDIT**

Also, don't use KeyListener on text components, use a combination of `DocumentListener` and key bindings instead. (Thanks to @MadProgrammer)

---

### Solution

```
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(console(outPipe, inWriter));
jsp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
frame.getContentPane().add(jsp);
```

---

### Output

[image]

Comment: thank you for the asnwer. It solved completely my problem :)

Comment: And you were doing so well, don't use KeyListener on text components, use a combination of DocumentListner and key bindings instead

Answer (score 1):

You can try with,

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] a) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(
                           JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                           JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        frame.setContentPane(pane);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
   }

}
```

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).